# How to check if an SQL query executed without error in ASP?

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

Here's my code:

```
if Request.Form("authorize") <> "" and request.form("delete") <> "true" then
    post_ids = Request.form("authorize")
    ids = split(post_ids, ",")

    For i = LBound(ids) to UBound(ids)
        sql = "update tbl_comments set authorized = 'true' where comment_id = " & ids(i)
        pageDB.execute(sql)
    Next

    message = "<div id=""succeed""><strong>Updated</strong>: Your comments have been approved.</div>"
end if
```

Instead of just setting "message" to the success message i'd like to do something along the lines of...

```
if(pageDB.execute(sql) was succesful) then
    message = "<div id=""succeed""><strong>Updated</strong>: Your comments have been approved.</div>"
else 
    message = "<div id=""error""><strong>Error</strong>: Your comments have not been approved.</div>"
end if
```

Comment: welcome, hackers, to my sql-injection kingdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your pageDB.execute(sql) within a try catch block

Something like this

```
message = "<div id=""succeed""><strong>Updated</strong>: Your comments have been approved.</div>"
Try
   pageDB.execute(sql)
Catch ex as Exception
   message = "<div id=""error""><strong>Error</strong>: Your comments have not been approved.</div>"
End Try
```

As the comment under your question suggests though, you should NOT update a SQL database like this as you exposing your database to hacking (very easy hacking)

Consider instead using command parameters. Lots of stuff on the net about this.

**Edit**

Now that we're talking about classic ASP error handling isn't as easy but still possible. Its a bigger subject so I'd recommend having a look at this article.

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/990603.htm

What type of object is pageDB?

Comment: Thanks for the code, you've got a fair point - is there an ASP equivalent of PHP's mysql_real_escape_string? 

Also: this is part of a CMS so the public won't have access.

Comment: AH, i've just realised I'm using ASP classic, so I don't think I can use Try Catch blocks.

Comment: @Sam: I've just written a complete answer for ASP classic, including parameterized prepared SQL statements and everything, before I realized that you had tagged your question "vb.net" (even though your code did not look like it). So I threw my answer away. How on earth did you manage to overlook that you are not on .NET?